# how to prevent alter table/trigger enable during fixture load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fixtures, rails-postgresql

I'm writing a rails application that reads data from another (legacy, cause it hasn't got any unit tests...) systems' tables.  It does not have any permissions on those tables (eventually, it will embrace and extend...)

I am sharing the same database (postgresql), and the two applications have separate database users.  When I load my initial fixtures, I get complaints because rails tries to alter 
all the tables to enable triggers.  Can I turn this off?

PGError: ERROR:  must be owner of relation auth_message
: ALTER TABLE "auth_message" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "django_session" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "django_site" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "django_admin_log" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE "django_content_type"...

Comment: It appears that this occurs for fixtures, from ./lib/active_record/fixtures.rb where it calls connection.disable_referential_integrity, and this does:
./lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:      def disable_referential_integrity ... there is no way I can see to easily disable this, I may write a rake task that monkey patches things.  In the meantime, I don't actually need that many things loaded in production (yet), so I'll do it manually.

Comment: Seems you've the approach right. But the permissions wrong, as suggested by Postgres. You need to be connected as superuser or as the owner of that table.

Answer (score -1):

The simple solution here is (logging in to pgAdmin or psql:

```
ALTER TABLE auth_message OWNER TO [your_username];
```

Then your commands will work.  You could also wrap the changes in a stored procedure which could be set SECURITY DEFINER to allow the changes by other users.

This may not be the answer you want to hear but basically you have only three options and this is by far the best.  In order to alter a table you must be the owner or be superuser, so....

1. You can do the above (recommended)
2. You can make sure both applications use the same username for schema changes (I assume there is a good reason you didn't do this).
3. You can make your db user a superuser, but that circumvents all other permissions checks.

I think your real solution is to make sure that db alterations are only coming from one app.

**EDIT:**

Actually I just thought of a better way to do this.

```
CREATE ROLE auth_message_owner WITH INHERIT NOLOGIN;
ALTER TABLE auth_message OWNER TO auth_message_owner;
GRANT auth_message_owner TO [app_user_1];
GRANT auth_message_owner TO [app_user_2];
```

This will let two different db users share ownership of the table.

Comment: Changing the ownership would just move the problem from the new application to the old (legacy) application. Hacking the old application is what we are trying to avoid.

Comment: added a little more clarification and other options.  I really think you need to make sure the alterations to the schema are only coming from one of the apps.

Comment: Hmmm I may have come up with a better answer.  Take a look at it.

Comment: The goal is that application "superuser" owns the tables.  This is neither applications' web server's login.  This really isn't a postgresql problem, although I would accept a postgresql solution that basically just does, "ignore enable/disable triggers errors"... it's really a rails problem. I usually have a third DB login that has enough alter privileges to run migrations, but I'd rather only have it own the new tables.